# Eclipse wasted white space on multiple panes

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know how to get rid of the superfluous white space at the top of a split editor pane in the latest version of eclipse (I think it's been around since Indigo actually).  To me it looks like the minimise and maximise buttons have been misplaced, see image below.

[image]

I know editor planes can be split in a different way, but that is a problem when I switch perspectives, or open new files (they always open in the original editor pane).

I know it is a minor thing, but wasted real estate on my screen annoys me.

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: It seems like it is somewhat related to the theme selected.  This was classic, which has a nicer toolbar.  When I switch to Windows 7 theme, the wasted space is reduced by about 65%, as the buttons (white I rarely use anyway) are much smaller.  The toolbar is really ugly though...   Compromises!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've dealt with this on numerous occasions and still occurs on Juno.

If you open two files in the order: `ITest.java`, `Test.java` and drag the second/rightmost file (`Test.java`) to create the split the whitepace will be created (as your picture). The fix is to drag the first/leftmost file (`ITest.java`) to create the split and then the whitespace is not created.